# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un ArrayList entre fragments?

Tags: android

¿Cómo pasar los datos que están en un `ArrayList` de un fragment `A` para utilizar estos mismos datos en un fragment "B"?.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución sería enviar el `ArrayList` por medio de una `interfaz`:

[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

pero otra que es común y yo uso es enviar el `ArrayList` cuando instancias el `Fragment`:

```
public class myFragment {

public static myFragment newInstance(@NonNull final ArrayList<String> fooList) {
    myFragment f = new myFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(“my_key”, fooList);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
} 


public ArrayList<String> getFoo() {
    final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    bundle != null ? bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mi_llave") : null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<Foo> fooList;

public void setFooList(ArrayList<Foo> fooList){
this.fooList = fooList;
}
}
```

Desde otro fragment u activity solamente tendrías que poner lo siguiente:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
myFragment.setFooList(fooList);
```